# Exporting an entire database to a different server dropped my original database

Tags: heidisql

What I did:

Opened the database I wanted exported, selected all the tables, then hit "Export Database as SQL". I selected the server I wanted it to go to, checked drop/create on tables and on databases and hit export.

I went to get coffee and when I came back I noticed the export failed and the original database was dropped entirely. I'm pretty sure it's not supposed to do that.

Am I doing something wrong here or did the program mess something up? I've used the same function before and it performed as expected.

Comment: And what is your question here?

Comment: I'm asking wether or not there's something I'm misunderstanding about the export function or if the program messed it up.

Comment: Well of course an export should not delete an existing database. But I doubt that is your _real_ question.

Comment: No, it really is. Maybe it's something concerning the server they're on, or who knows what other factor.

Answer (score 0):

In earlier versions of HeidiSQL, SSH tunneled sessions could have used the same local port for the plink.exe process. So, when you have a source session and a target session both with the same local SSH port, there is a chance HeidiSQL is executing queries on the source server which are supposed to run on the target server.

In recent versions of HeidiSQL, the local port is checked for availability before using it for plink. If it's not open, HeidiSQL tries the next higher ones (up to the next 20 ones), and if all are in use, you get an error message.